# How can I list the heads of an expression?

Tags: core-language

How can I check that a fraction contains only multiplication and power? I would like to check if it contains only the heads of Power and Times. I am wondering how to get a list of heads for a fraction. There is the option Heads->True, but I don't think there's a dedicated function for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a function that works.

```wl
ExpressionHeads[expression_] := 
 Complement[Cases[expression, _, All, Heads -> True], 
  Cases[expression, _, All, Heads -> False]]
```

Here's an example of using the function.

```wl
randomPolynomial = RandomPolynomial[\[FormalP]]
```

The output is

```wl
46 + 51 \[FormalP] + 82 \[FormalP]^2 - 12 \[FormalP]^3 - 
 68 \[FormalP]^4
```

I used the ResourceFunction PacletizeResourceFunction to pacletize Jon Mcloone's ResourceFunction RandomPolynomial.

```wl
ExpressionHeads[randomPolynomial]
```

returns

```wl
{Plus, Power, Times}
```